# Change CSS of a website with Chrome Extension - Some styles can't be changed

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

**Now working.**

I have a working Chrome Extension that will give me an injected stylesheet on the webpage I want but there are some styles I can not seem to overwrite.

For example, looking at the current Google home page I can inspect the empty area below and see there is no background color set. In the Styles section, if I click the "New Style Rule" button, (large plus sign) it gives me the correct (location?) for the rule ".o3j99.qarstb" when I copy the rule and add it as is to the CSS file it works. I get the injected stylesheet section added to the Styles and the color changes.

```
.o3j99.qarstb {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

I can also add this to the CSS and change the "About" and "Store" text size at the top left.

```
body, input, button {
    font-size: 27px !important;
}
```

I'm trying to do something similar to another webpage but it's CSS or styles are more complex and it's hard to figure out if an injected stylesheet will even work. They do work when I make the change in place in the existing rule.

Here is the existing style rule:

```
.quixote .qx-grid .editor_grid tbody .input-group input {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

I added it to the styles.CSS file like this but it seems to be ignored as I can't find an injected stylesheet for it.

```
.quixote .qx-grid .editor_grid tbody .input-group input {
    width: 900px !important;
}
```

This is the popup.js file. **(Adding "allFrames: true" to the end of the insertCSS target got it working.)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.reset').click(function() {
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
var activeTab = tabs[0];
/*alert("Button Reset");*/
        chrome.scripting.removeCSS({
            target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
            files: ["styles.css"]
});
/*chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"buttonclicked": "reset"});*/
});
})

$('.format').click(function() {
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
var activeTab = tabs[0];
/*alert("Button Wider");*/
        chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
            target: { tabId: activeTab.id, allFrames: true },
            files: ["styles.css"]
        });
/*chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"buttonclicked": "wider"});*/
});
/*alert("Hello");*/
})
})
```

This is the content.js file. **(Not sure why this was added but same code in the popup.js works even with all this commented out.)**

```
/*var copy = $('body').clone()

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender,     sendResponse) {
if( request.buttonclicked === "reset" ) {
    $('body').html($(copy))
    }
if( request.buttonclicked === "wider" ) {
        chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
            target: { tabId: tabId },
            files: ["styles.css"]
        });
    }
})*/
```

This is the element the above rules are in.

```
<input class="form-control required" type="text" name="_obj__TIMESHEETITEMS_0_-_obj__PROJECTID" id="_obj__TIMESHEETITEMS_0_-_obj__PROJECTID" autocomplete="off" size="28" placeholder="Project" tabindex="0" style="min-width: 110px;">
```

It's a secure site so I can't post a link. Here is an example of the Table, I'd like to widen the first two columns.
[image: Example of Table, I'd like to widen the first tow columns.]

Here is a pic of the inspect page, showing the element and two rules that I can manually change but can't with the CSS file.
[image]

What the "Stylus" extension adds and that works.
[image]

Comment: Can you give a link to a page where the problem occurs?

Comment: Try inserting a rule with a higher specificity like this: `.quixote .qx-grid .editor_grid tbody .input-group input:not(#_) {  width: 900px !important  }`

Comment: So just adding the `:not(#_)` part on the end? Was the Semicolon after  `!important` not needed? I tried with and without and the change did not work. :( On this same page I can do a simple background color change. `.qx-appbar .qx-navbar-app {
    background-color: #8ceba9 !important;
}`

Comment: May be that CSS rule is inside an iframe and you are inserting your CSS rules in the top frame. That could explain why it doesn't work. But without a reproducible test case, I can only guess. Try using the CSS rule I gave you in the extension "Stylus". It should override the CSS rule at `qxform.min.css:9` if it's injected in the same frame.

Comment: Ok, my original rule works in the "Stylus" extension. Never used it before. Is there no way to get my extension to do the same? Added a pic above of what it looks like on the inspect screen.

Comment: If it works in Stylus, then you are doing something wrong in your extension. Show the relevant part of your code where you inject the CSS. That's where the problem is likely to be.

Comment: Sorry it's been so long. I've posted the styles.CSS above and the "Stylus" extension adds. Did you want to see the popip.js? I'll try to add all the files I'm using above.

Comment: Try injecting the CSS in all frames, i.e. pass the `allFrames: true` parameter to the `chrome.scripting.insertCSS` function.

Comment: That worked (Thanks!!!) but the reset button using the 'chrome.scripting.removeCSS' command puts the test background-color change back but not the new width setting. I would also like to add a variable to the popup so the user can use a slider or enter a number.